# Map list in React using typescript json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, typescript

I am using typescript in react first time. Trying to map an json array object but can not access the data in the array. e.g. Trying to get data.name but it is givin me an error Property 'name' does not exist on type 'JSON' but when I console log the data it is showing me the name. How can I map the object when I am using TypeScript?

````
<tbody>
{dataSeries.map((data: JSON) => (
<tr>
{console.log(data)}
<th>{data.name}</th>
<td>Mark</td>
<td>Otto</td>
<td>@mdo</td>
</tr>
))}
</tbody>```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell Typescript what the object is going to look like. e.g.

```js
<tbody>
{dataSeries.map((data:{name: string}) => (
<tr>
{console.log(data)}
<th>{data.name}</th>
<td>Mark</td>
<td>Otto</td>
<td>@mdo</td>
</tr>
))}
</tbody>
```